# How remove extra padding above Jetpack Compose OutlinedTextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to put OutlinedTextField into the Column after Box element like this

```
@Composable
fun Header() {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan)
        ) {
            Text("Header")
        }

        OutlinedTextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = {
                Text("Enter header")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Borders added to see exact size of elements. It looks like this
[image]
with extra 8dp padding above, but when I use TextField instead of OutlinedTextField there are no extra space

```
@Composable
fun Header() {
    Column {
        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan)
        ) {
            Text("Header")
        }

        TextField(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .border(1.dp, Color.Cyan),
            value = "",
            onValueChange = {},
            placeholder = {
                Text("Enter header")
            }
        )
    }
}
```

[image]
I need to know why it is happening and how to solve it

Version of library is "androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-alpha10"

Comment: Both codes produce the same padding on Android studio preview

Answer (score 4):

The Padding above `OutlinedTextField` is there because the label moves to the top when in focus, which requires space.

[image: Material Specs]

If you don't want this feature, you can create your own outlined text field composable by modifying `BasicTextField`.